# Install Jdk 8 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, java, openjdk

I have added a repo by doing:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

output:

```
Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 2):

The PPA your added has been [discontinued due to licensing changes.](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

Use this [new PPA for Oracle Java 11 and 12](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java) (not OpenJDK). <strike>Since Java is backward compatible, all your Java 8 programs should work in  Java 11 (at least in theory).</strike>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Oracle JDK, you need to download the .tar.gz archive from the [Oracle JDK website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).  From there, open a terminal and copy or move the file to /usr/jdk (you might need to create the directory "jdk" first) by using `cp <path to downloaded file> /usr/jdk/<desired filename>` and extract it with `tar -zxvf <the filename>`.
If you have difficulty with this I recommend checking out [Oracle's documentation](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml).  It is very helpful.  Also, if you don't need version 8 and could do with JDK 11 or 12 there is a .deb package for these newer versions that makes installing and enabling the jdk much easier.